# Given a list of image names, how can I search my local website file contents for the image names?

Tags: node.js, batch-file, full-text-search

My goal is to remove the image files from a website that are not used by any website files (html, css, js, etc).

I was able to export a list of all image file locations using the answer here: https://superuser.com/questions/324882/export-windows-7-search-results-to-a-text-file

I have a text file with a list of images, such as:
/images/photos/foo.jpg
/images/icons/bar.png
/images/banners/baz.gif

How can I search the file contents of all html, CSS and JavaScript files on my local copy of the website for the image names on my list (above) and return a new list of images that are not found?

I'm using Windows. Is there a batch process or Node.js technique that could be used?

Comment: I suggest to use free [Xenu's Link Sleuth](http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html). It is a small tool, very easy to install and use which scans your website offline or online or mixed for broken links and also orphaned files very quickly. The HTML report created after the scan contains among the list of broken links the list of orphaned files which are the files not referenced by any page of the website.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio, so I opted for a similar tool to Xenu called "Find Unused Files". https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RobertHoffmann.FindUnusedFiles I had to adjust settings in "Find Unused Files" so that my images that compile to sprites do not get listed as unused. I copied the list of unused images out of "Find Unused Files" and saved it to a text file "unusedImages.txt". Then, I ran this Node.js script to delete the images: https://plnkr.co/edit/k7kptamD82kJvc0zJUla